# Pipenv Django installation

Tags: django, pipenv

I got back into django after a while.
I learned to install django using pipenv originally and after coming back to it, the installation is failing for new projects? I'm not doing anything crazy, I'm literally just trying to start a new django project. I've seen some other posts on SO that mention the same error with Heroku, but I'm not using Heroku, just trying to install Django.

I'm running python3 version 3.8.9 and pipenv version 2022.3.24
I get this error:

```
    Error:  An error occurred while installing django!
Error text: Collecting django
  Using cached Django-4.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.1 MB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
  Using cached sqlparse-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting backports.zoneinfo
  Using cached backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1.tar.gz (74 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.5.2
  Using cached asgiref-3.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: backports.zoneinfo
  Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build backports.zoneinfo

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [43 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports
      copying src/backports/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_zoneinfo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_tzpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      running egg_info
      writing src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      /private/var/folders/fv/6rw743dn5xd9vhl84r0px7800000gn/T/pip-build-env-8tu6_78f/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'docs'
      warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'docs'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_output'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      adding license file 'licenses/LICENSE_APACHE'
      writing manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/py.typed -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
      
      running build_ext
      building 'backports.zoneinfo._czoneinfo' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/lib
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -I/Users/justinlee/.local/share/virtualenvs/practice-dj-XarTy6I1/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -c lib/zoneinfo_module.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/lib/zoneinfo_module.o -std=c99
      lib/zoneinfo_module.c:1:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
      #include "Python.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for backports.zoneinfo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: pipenv install django~=3.2.0 --python 3.10